# react-redux-firebase login promise resolving before auth state is updated, causing render troubles

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-router-redux, react-redux-firebase

I am using redux-form, react-redux-firebase, along with react-router-redux and react-router.

When logging in a user with a redux-form connected form, in the onSubmit callback function, I am using the react-redux-firebase function from the `withFirebase` HOC called `props.firebase.login()`. Inside the return of this promise, I am attempting to use react-router to navigate to a "protected" view of mine.

This all works well and looks like this:

```
    export default withFirebase( 
        connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
            reduxForm({
                form: SINGLE_PAGE_FORMS.login, 
                onSubmit: (values, dispatch, props) => {
                    const { firebase } = props;
                    const { username: email, password } = values;

                    firebase.login({
                        email,
                        password,

                    }).then(response => {
                        if(!!response) {
                            dispatch(
                                openNotificationCenterAC({ message: 'Successfully logged in!', messageType: MESSAGE_TYPE_SUCCESS })
                            );

                            // The problem here with login is that the Private Route has not yet seen the Uid update and therefore 
                            // won't load a private route. I need to know the UID is in state before navigating to dashboard.
                            dispatch( push( ROUTE_OBJS.SECURED[ROUTES.DASHBOARD].path ) );
                            dispatch( reset(SINGLE_PAGE_FORMS.login) );
                        }

                    }).catch(error => {
                        dispatch(
                            openNotificationCenterAC({ message: error.message, messageType: MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR })
                        );
                    });
                },

            })(LoginContainerView)
        )
    );
```

The trouble (as seen in comments) is that I have switched over (today) to using a really cool new way of making some of my routes Private. I used the examples found in [this link here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) to create this concept.

My Private component looks like this:

```
export default class PrivateRouteView extends Component {

    render() {
        const {
            key,
            auth,
            path,
            renderRoute,
            showErrorMessage,

        } = this.props;

        const { uid } = auth;

        return (
            <Route
                exact
                key={key}
                path={path}
                render={
                    (!!uid && isLoaded(auth) && !isEmpty(auth)) ? renderRoute : 
                        props => {

                            return (
                                <Redirect
                                    to={{
                                        pathname: '/login',
                                        state: { from: props.location }
                                    }} />
                            );
                        }
                } />
        );
    }
}
```

The `auth` prop here is from the `withFirebase` HOC injection. It's attached to `this.props.firebase.auth`.

**The Problem**

Whenever I successfully log in, get the user data returned to me in the `.then` function of the `firebase.login()` promise... by the time I get to the dispatch of .push navigation, the PrivateRoute has re-rendered without the new auth object and never re-renders.

I can step through and watch it. It goes:

1. Login success
2. Enter into `.then` function
3. Notify user of login success
4. Change navigation to dashboard view
5. PrivateRoute component re-renders and see's no UID or auth
6. `firebase.login` promise entirely resolved
7. Application state update completes and firebase.auth now has Uid and all other profile/auth objects in state
8. Container to react-router BrowserRouter, Switch and Route's runs normally
9. View attached to this container re-renders fine, down to the function where I return the PrivateRoute components
10. PrivateRoute render method is never reached on the second render, the one where the `firebase.login` user data finally makes it into firebase.auth object state. So now I am authorized, however it never see's the new auth object because of no rendering...